# Linear independent of lines

Tags: linear-algebra

I  want to find lines pass through origin such their slopes are linearly independent over rational numbers . What kind of conditions should I make to get these lines.

Comment: Linearly independent over what?

Comment: Working in 2-d, it seems just select a set of slopes linearly independent over rationals. Also as lulu asks, you need to say independent over what field.

Comment: I fixed now. Over rational numbers

Comment: Do you just want a list?  taking, say, $\{\sqrt {p_n} \}$ as $p_n$ spans the primes is good enough.  Or $\{e^n\}$ for that matter.

Comment: You mean lines with slopes $\{\sqrt{p_n}\}$

Comment: Yes, I am giving a sequence of slopes. Probably easier to just take $\{e^n\}$.

Comment: Okay, how bout if I need the slopes of the lines are algebraically independent

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets) is a useful discussion.